# Top Navigation with BassCSS and CSS3

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to imitate what I consider is a great design for top navigation. The top navigation is from this website here: [Giphy](http://giphy.com)

For my layout I've been using BassCSS latest version which is the `Basscss v8.0.1`. Here's what I have so far:

HTML:

```
  <div class="clearfix xs-hide mx-auto bg-white flex flex-justify md-col-12 lg-col-8 mb1">
    <div class="col mx-auto center border-bottom border-red strong-border px3">
      <a href="" class=" caps bold red h4 text-decoration-none">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col mx-auto center border-bottom border-green strong-border px3">
      <a href="" class=" caps bold green h4 text-decoration-none">Categories</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col mx-auto center border-bottom border-purple strong-border px3">
      <a href="" class=" caps bold purple h4 text-decoration-none">Tags</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col mx-auto center border-bottom border-aqua strong-border px3">
      <a href="" class=" caps bold aqua h4 text-decoration-none">Information</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col mx-auto center border-bottom border-yellow strong-border px3">
      <a href="" class=" caps bold yellow h4 text-decoration-none">Search</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix xs-hide flex mx-auto md-col-12 lg-col-8 mb1">
    <label for="search-input" class="hide">Search</label>
    <input
      type="search"
      id="search-input"
      class="flex-auto py1 px1 m0 field not-rounded"
      placeholder="Search term">
    <button class="border black bg-aqua not-rounded">Go</button>
  </div>
```

The CSS files for BassCSS can be found at the official website (I can't post more than two links). I just extended on little thing:

```
.strong-border{
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
}
```

And that gives me the desire strong border. You can see my version in codepen. That's what I have already but it isn't as good looking as the original because of that white-space problem (Before the links there's some white-space) and this is caused because the links are centered in their container. Also, I don't want the background color to be **black** and so I was looking for it to look great on white.

Can you please help me to get it a little bit more like the original?

BTW, here's a codepen [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKmVxQ) with my version on it so you can go ahead and see/play it. :-)

Comment: what padding problem are you referring to ? could you give a some more details ?

Comment: Ok, see this image, I added border on the element containing the links http://imgur.com/Zhy4dix ... you see that there is some white-space before the links, I'm trying to avoid that! I'll edit my question so it will be clearer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`:first-child`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) and [`:last-child`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) to specify that you don't want the margin left respectively right on the extremity items.

Something like this:

```
div.mb1 div:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
div.mb1 div:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

where `div.mb1` is the parent and so the properties are specified on the first and last child `div`.

Here is the [updated codepen](http://codepen.io/lulylulu/pen/eZejgo).

Hope I got the problem right.

Comment: Wow! White-space does make the difference, right? You got it right. Thank you a lot! :-)